# getting error in type casting - Input string was not in a correct format

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm getting an error in this line `int number = int.Parse(Days);`

> Input string was not in a correct format.

```
public string GetApprovedLimit(int CategoryId)
{
    SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(GetConnectionString());
    SqlCommand cmdLog = new SqlCommand();
    cmdLog.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmdLog.Connection = connection;
    cmdLog.Transaction = Trans;
    connection.Open();
    cmdLog.CommandText = "ApprovedDays";
    cmdLog.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CategoryId", CategoryId);
    string Days = cmdLog.ExecuteScalar() == null ? "1" : cmdLog.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
    connection.Close();
    int number = int.Parse(Days);
    Days = (number + 20).ToString(); // Added extra 20 days for late link submission
    return Days;
}
```

stored procedure:

```
Create Proc [dbo].[ApprovedDays]
(
    @CategoryId int
)
as begin

select ApprovedDays from tbl_Category where CategoryId=@CategoryId

end
GO
```

Comment: What is `Days` exactly? Did you debug your code and check it?

Comment: The conditional operator executes the query twice. Store it in a variable.

Comment: Show your complete code.

Comment: sorry i cant debug the code. in locally im not getting error. in remote server im getitng this error , i cant debug wat is the value im getting in number i cant find.

Comment: You need to show us the code Only then there is a chance that we can help you.

Comment: wat code u need ? updated code. if any other code needed tell me

Comment: _Well_, if you can't debug the code that you work, looks like you have bigger problem rather than an exception.

Comment: im just saying i cant debug onsite code. locally im not getting any error.

Comment: is procedure returning any value?or is days null?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- If the row does not exist the result of `cmdLog.ExecuteScalar()` is `null`, no problem.
- If the row exists but has `NULL` in this column, the result of `cmdLog.ExecuteScalar()` is `DBNull.Value`, `DBNull.Value.ToString()` returns an empty string which causes your exception.

Instead you should cast it to the corect type which seems to be an `int`:

```
int days = 1;
object obj = cmdLog.ExecuteScalar();
if(obj != null && DBNull.Value != obj)
{
    days = (int) obj;
}
```

Apart from that, the  conditional operator executes the query twice. Store it in a variable.

Comment: can i use Convert.ToInt32?

Comment: @krishnamohan: yes you can, but isn't it an `int` in the database anyway?

Answer (score 1):

From your question it looks like you are trying to parse an empty string.
Things you can try

```
int number = string.IsNullOrEmpty(days) ? 0 : int.Parse(days);
```

or

```
     if (int.TryParse(days, out number))
        {// Conversion succeeded}
     else
       {
         //failed
        }
```

MSDN says:`int.TryParse` Converts the string representation of a number to its 32-bit signed integer equivalent. A return value indicates whether the conversion succeeded